# Get a list of all Purview Business Assets through REST API endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-rest-api, azure-purview

In order to build an integration between Azure Purview and other third party systems via Azure Logic Apps i need to get a **list of all Business Assets GUIDs** via the REST API ([List which can be seen here in the WebApp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2ysF.png))

In order to retrieve detailed Entity information I then use the following request: (which is working for manually picked GUIDs):

GET `https://{{purview_account}}.catalog.purview.azure.com/api/atlas/v2/entity/guid/{GUID}` (Authenticaton via Bearer Token)

#### What i tried so far

According to this [API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/purview/?view=rest-purview-datamapdataplane-2023-09-01) i tried playing around with the Discovery Endpoint, but cannot do a working request.

Came up with:

- POST `https://{{purview_account}}.purview.azure.com/api/atlas/v2/search/query?api-version=2023-09-01`
- POST `https://{{purview_account}}.purview.azure.com/datamap/api/search/query?api-version=2023-09-01`

All using the Body: `{ "keywords": "*" }`

Which results in a 404 Not Found Error: {"error":{"code":"ResourceNotFound","message":"Resource not found"}}

Can someone please tell me the syntax for a request fulfilling my requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to get the list of all Purview Business Assets using below URL-

```
POST  https://{{purview_account}}.purview.azure.com/datamap/api/search/query?api-version=2023-09-01
```

Before invoking above URL, you need to grant `user_impersonation` permission to the app registered in Microsoft Entra ID.

[image]

You need to generate the token as shown below

[image]

Use the token while invoking `POST {endpoint}/datamap/api/search/query?api-version=2023-09-01`.

I am also using request body as `{ "keywords": "*" }`.

[image]